# Spring Drop-down List to limit list length to show only 10 options if list size > 10

Tags: spring, hibernate, jstl

I have a problem trying to limit my drop-down list to show only x amount of items out of 50 items to include a vertical scrollbar. Is there a way to add inline CSS or methods as I'm not very familiar with the Spring framework.

Tried using things like size=10 but this just changes it to a listbox with size 10 which is not of 'drop-down' type.

```
<div class="pure-control-group">
  <label for="centres"><fmt:message key="addinfo.centres" />    <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <div class="field input-medium">
      <form:select class="input-medium"  path="centres" >
        <c:forEach items="${centreBean.centresList}" var="centre">
            <option value="${centre.codePk}">${centre.desc}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<c:forEach items="${centreBean.centresList}" var="centre" varStatus="status">
  <c:if test="${status.index < 10}">
    <option value="${centre.codePk}">${centre.desc}</option>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I tried this but it only limits to showing the 10 items which is good, but how do I add a vertical scrollbar to the dropdown to show the others in the list?

Comment: You may have to use JavaScript or CSS, for example, `overflow-y: scroll;`.

Comment: Yup, I wantd to use the overflow-y: scroll method but I do not know exactly where I should put it inline, like it does not show any effect